# Can bittorrent peers handle seeding large numbers of idle torrents

Tags: bittorrent, bigdata

I'm considering using bittorrent for a large data dissemination problem where the data source is petascale and users will want up to several terabytes.  Some details

- Number of torrents potentially in the millions
- torrent sizes ranging from 100Mb to 100Gb
- A stable set of clusters around the world capable of acting as seeders each holding a large subset of the total torrents (say 60% on average)
- A relatively small number of simultaneous users (less than 100) wanting to download on average a few terabytes of data.

I expect the number of active torrents to be small compared to the total available  but quality of service is important so there must be several seeders for each torrent or some mechanism for launching new seeders.

My question is can bittorrent clients handle seeding huge numbers of torrents, most of which are idle?  Would I need to stripe torrents across the seeders in a cluster or could each node be seeding all torrents it has access to?  Which client would do the best job?  Are there any tools for managing clusters of seeders?

I am assuming that trackers can be made to scale to this level.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 main problems:

1. Each torrent (typically) needs to announce to a tracker periodically, this might end up using a significant amount of bandwidth.
2. The bittorrent client itself need to be written in a way to scale with a large number of torrents

As for the tracker traffic, let's assume you have 1 million torrents, the typical re-announce interval is 30 minutes, but some tracker has it set to 1 hour. Let's be conservative and assume your tracker uses 1 hour announce intervals. You will have to make 1 million GET requests per hour, let's say each request is 400 bytes up and 100 bytes down (assuming most responses will not contain any peers), that's about 111 kB/s up and 28 kB/s down constantly. That's not so bad, but keep in mind that TCP requires an extra round-trip for establishing connections, so that's another 40 bytes down and 40 bytes up.

This can be mitigated by only using [UDP trackers](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html). Then you would only need a single connect-message, and you can reuse the connection ID for each announce. Each announce message would then be 100 bytes, and the returned message would be a bit more compact as well, let's assume 60 bytes. That would get you 28 kB/s up and 16kB/s down, just to keep the torrents announced. For this you would need a client with decent udp tracker support (one that caches the connection ID for instance).

Not too bad, assuming that's insignificant compared to the actual data your seeds would send.

However, you don't necessarily need to stripe your torrents across separate data centers, you could also use an HTTP server to seed the torrents. All major bittorrent clients support http seeding, and you wouldn't have to worry about announcing to the tracker (the URL is burned into the .torrent itself).

As for a client that scales well with torrents, I don't know for sure, I haven't done any measurements. It should be fairly straightforward to just generate a million random torrents and try to load it up.

I have done some optimization work in [libtorrent rasterbar](http://libtorrent.org) to make it scale well with many torrents, I haven't tried millions though.

I've written a blog post on this topic, [here](http://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/01/seeding-a-million-torrents).

Comment: Arvid has posted more tuning tips for libtorrent here: http://libtorrent.org/tuning.html Similar optimizations can be done to other clients.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for [Hekate](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/hekate/)
It's in, at best, pre-alpha right now, but it's quite nearly what you're describing.

Comment: If you're looking for tracker software that scales to that level as well, you're looking for [opentracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/), which is what The Pirate Bay used to run before they shut all their trackers down. With those two things you should have no significant issue distributing your data.

Comment: Hekate seems to be dead. Too bad -- the idea was very nice.

Answer (score 1):

To not collapse under the overhead of useless tracker announces and scrapes in the millions (and that in every announce interval), you have to restrict your seeding clusters to only load the current working set of items that are requested right now. Downloaders need to get (download) the .torrent file from a central place anyway, and that could trigger loading it into the seeding clusters. Alternatively, determine activity for a particcular info-hash by recognizing announces that do NOT originate from one of your seed clusters.

rTorrent has fast-resume (meaning no hashing happens when an appropriately prepared .torrent is loaded), and is controllable via xmlrpc so you can decommission idle items. That way, a .torrent download can trigger the actual data to be available for the next 24 hours, or as long as there's activity in the swarm.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol allows for this, but I do not know which clients would scale to millions of torrents. In the worst case, you would have to write your own seed-only client.

The protocol feature most relevant to your use case is that, when a peer connects to another, the connecting peer is supposed to send the torrent's info-hash first. This means that a single listening TCP port could be used to seed an unlimited amount of torrents, with almost zero resources used when idle.

This can be found on [The BitTorrent Protocol Specification](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html):

> If both sides don't send the same value, they sever the connection. The one possible exception is if a downloader wants to do multiple downloads over a single port, they may wait for incoming connections to give a download hash first, and respond with the same one if it's in their list.

I also found the same on this [Bittorrent Protocol Specification v1.0](http://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification):

> The initiator of a connection is expected to transmit their handshake immediately. The recipient may wait for the initiator's handshake, if it is capable of serving multiple torrents simultaneously (torrents are uniquely identified by their info_hash).

However, there is one thing that would increase your load, and it is the tracker. With the normal tracker protocol, each client has to periodically announce to the tracker each torrent it has, together with information like how much it has uploaded. With millions of torrents, this would present a somewhat high load. If you were writing your own mass-seed-only client, a separate protocol to announce your seeders to the tracker would be a good idea.